# NotFoundError: encountered while using function tf.train.latest_checkpoint()

Tags: python, tensorflow

I built a CNN classification model and saved the checkpoints while training. After running this code.

```
checkpoint_dir = "/home/user/cnn-model/trained_model_1506946529/"
checkpoint_file = tf.train.latest_checkpoint(checkpoint_dir + 'checkpoints')
```

I get the error:

```
NotFoundError                    Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-60-8de4d687f60c> in <module>()
  5     checkpoint_dir += '/'
  6 print (checkpoint_dir + 'checkpoints')
  ----> 7 checkpoint_file = tf.train.latest_checkpoint(checkpoint_dir +    'checkpoints')
  8 print (checkpoint_file)

  /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py in latest_checkpoint(checkpoint_dir, latest_filename)
 1612     v1_path = _prefix_to_checkpoint_path(ckpt.model_checkpoint_path,
 1613                                          saver_pb2.SaverDef.V1)
 -> 1614     if file_io.get_matching_files(v2_path) or     file_io.get_matching_files(
 1615         v1_path):
 1616       return ckpt.model_checkpoint_path

 /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/lib/io/file_io.py in get_matching_files(filename)
 330           # Convert the filenames to string from bytes.
 331           compat.as_str_any(matching_filename)
 --> 332           for single_filename in filename
 333           for matching_filename in pywrap_tensorflow.GetMatchingFiles(
 334               compat.as_bytes(single_filename), status)

/usr/lib/python3.5/contextlib.py in __exit__(self, type, value, traceback)
 64         if type is None:
 65             try:
 ---> 66                 next(self.gen)
 67             except StopIteration:
 68                 return

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/errors_impl.py in raise_exception_on_not_ok_status()
464           None, None,
465           compat.as_text(pywrap_tensorflow.TF_Message(status)),
--> 466           pywrap_tensorflow.TF_GetCode(status))
467   finally:
468     pywrap_tensorflow.TF_DeleteStatus(status)

NotFoundError: /home/user/cnn-model/trained_model_1506946529/checkpoints
```

The file location exists and so does the checkpoints, what can i do to mitigate it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tf.train.latest_checkpoint takes a folder name as arg. Just change it to:

```
checkpoint_file = tf.train.latest_checkpoint(checkpoint_dir)
```